# Understanding the elasticsearch slow query log format

Tags: performance, elasticsearch, logging

For troubleshooting a performance issue on Elasticsearch cluster, I started looking into the slow logs for some indices and **noticed below strange thing:**

**types[estype], stats[], search_type[QUERY_THEN_FETCH], total_shards[6],**,

Slow logs show that Elasticsearch query was hitting six shards, which is just not possible as my index has just two primary shards with two replicas** and according to Elasticsearch documentation, for a search query **ES will send a request to either a primary shard or replica shard but not to both**.

So According to the above logic, Elasticsearch must query only two shards, then how come in my slow logs it's happening as six(6) shards, and this is causing doubts in my mind for the slowness of these queries.

Note:- If I grab the ES query from slow-log and directly hit using `curl,` in response, it shows correct two shards only.

Comment: Is it possible that you have entries in your query_slow_logs that originate from other indices (maybe system indices such as .monitoring*, .kibana* etc)? You also may want to check the indices you have in your cluster and their slowlog configuration (`GET _cat/indices?v`)

Slow logs are written on every single node and yes, your understanding is correct: a search request hits either the primary or replica, but not both.

Comment: @DanielSchneiter thanks for your reply, but these are my main web-app indices which store the user generated data and not originating from system indices like u mentioned from kibana or monitoring, also I know the slow log configuration and would add them to my question as well but I didn't find any unusual thing there

Comment: Since it should hit maximum 24 shards, yet you see 48, my guess is that you're hitting an alias that spans two indexes. Is that plausible?

Comment: @Val, I'll check this and get back to you

Comment: @Val, found the reason, it wasn't due to alias.